# "File does not exist" error in Inno Setup when using {src} in Source

Tags: inno-setup

I have a problem when defining a file in the Inno Setup `Files` section. Some times when I use `{src}` constant and compile it I get an error that says the file doesn't exist.

```
Source: "{src}\dontReadMe.txt"; DestDir: "{tmp}";
```

And here is what I get:

[image: why {src} is there]

That happened more when I use `Flags dontcopy;`.
Look at `{src}` in the path why it's there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the [documentation for `Source` parameter](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=filessection&anchor=Source) says:

> Constants may only be used when the `external` flag is specified, because the compiler does not do any constant translating itself.